# Configure two ethernet interface on Ubuntu

Tags: ethernet, 22.04, netplan

I'm trying to configure two Ethernet connections on the same computer running on Ubuntu but every attempts that I have made doesn't allow me to enable both Ethernet connections at the same time and I don't understand why. To have a better understanding of what I want to do, here is a description of the three involved computers represented at the following picture:

[image: 1]

- Computer A: my personal computer (running on windows) which is connected to internet
- Computer B: a computer running on Ubuntu 22.04, connected via Ethernet to internet and to the computer C
- C : a Ubuntu server 22.04 which is only connected to the computer B via Ethernet

I want to have access to the computer C from the computer A with SSH.
I already have set static ips on computers B and C:

- On computer B: xx.yy.zz.101 for the Ethernet port linked to the Ethernet port of the computer C
- On computer B: xx.yy.zz.100 for the Ethernet port connected to internet
- On computer C: xx.yy.zz.102 for the Ethernet port linked to the Ethernet port of the computer B

So, I should be able to access first from computer A to computer B with the command:

```
ssh xx.yy.zz.100
```

and then from computer B to C with the command:

```
ssh xx.yy.zz.102
```

Nevertheless, I can do only one of the two connections (depending on which one is active). The netplan configuration file of the computer B is:

```
---
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp35s0: # Connection to computer C
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [xx.yy.zz.101/24] # Need to configure a static ip
      gateway4: xx.yy.zz.1
    enp42s0: # Connection to internet
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [xx.yy.zz.100/24] # Need to configure a static ip
      gateway4: xx.yy.zz.1
      nameservers:
      - addresses: [a.b.c.d, e.f.g.h]
```

and the command "ip a" shows:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group    default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp35s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:13:3b:0f:8f:36 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.102.100.101/24 brd 10.102.100.255 scope global enp35s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::213:3bff:fe0f:8f36/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp36s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:13:3b:0f:8f:37 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: enp42s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 2c:f0:5d:9a:e0:2c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.102.100.100/24 brd 10.102.100.255 scope global enp42s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::2ef0:5dff:fe9a:e02c/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Can you help me to understand why the two Ethernet interfaces can't be used at the same time? I already tried several options, like using the routes option with some priority but I have never succeeded to do what I want so I don't know which is simple way to do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I do this all the time and it works just fine.

Your problem is with the `gateway4`. One computer can have at most one gateway to work properly. Otherwise, it won't know where to send traffic with "other IP addresses" (other than your directly accessible LAN).

So comment our or delete the second `gateway4`. Only have the one that goes to the Internet.

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp35s0: # Connection to computer C
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [xx.yy.zz.101/24] # Need to configure a static ip
      #gateway4: xx.yy.zz.1 -- REMOVE THIS ONE
    enp42s0: # Connection to internet
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [xx.yy.zz.100/24] # Need to configure a static ip
      gateway4: xx.yy.zz.1
      nameservers:
      - addresses: [a.b.c.d, e.f.g.h]
```

Note that you will have a `gateway4` setup on computer C. You just don't want it on computer B because sending traffic to C from B when it's intended for the Internet won't work.

Answer (score 0):

well, the output of ip a shows the interfaces `enp35s0` and `enp36s0`. you try to configure `enp35s0` and `enp42s0`. duplicate use of `gateway4` is the next issue. use `gateway4` only once and use dedicated routes.

Answer (score 0):

Tank you for your reponse ! Removing the gateway for the first interface AND adding the line "renderer: NetworkManager" at the same indentation level than "version: 2" solve my problem.
The configuration file is now:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp35s0: # Connection to computer C
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [xx.yy.100.101/24] # Need to configure a static ip
    enp42s0: # Connection to internet
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [xx.yy.100.100/24] # Need to configure a static ip
      gateway4: xx.yy.100.1
      nameservers:
      - addresses: [a.b.c.d, e.f.g.h]
```

I can now connect from my computer A to C via B. Nevertheless, It is very strange that, now, i can only access to B with Wifi and not with ethernet (connection timed out). Also, i can't ping computer B from A when I use the ethernet connection

When I reset the network config of computer B, i can access with Wifi and ethernet so it's linked to the current netplan configuration. I tried to find the answer but I still have this problem. Have you an idea ?

The ip configuration of my laptop (computer A) is:

```
Carte réseau sans fil Wi-Fi :

   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . : -------------
   Adresse IPv6 de liaison locale. . . . .: -------------
   Adresse IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . .: xx.yy.80.204
   Masque de sous-réseau. . . . . . . . . : 255.255.248.0
   Passerelle par défaut. . . . . . . . . : xx.yy.80.1

Carte Ethernet Ethernet :

   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . : -------------
   Adresse IPv6 de liaison locale. . . . .: -------------
   Adresse IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . .: xx.yy.100.27
   Masque de sous-réseau. . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Passerelle par défaut. . . . . . . . . : xx.yy.100.1
```